# Three monitors without external GPUs

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, motherboard, external-display, cryptomining

Is it possible to connect three monitors using only the motherboard and get distinct output?
The motherboard is `MSI Pro Carbon Z270` and it has one HDMI and one DVI ports.

I cannot use external GPUs because they are mining cryptocurrency and tweaked too far away from normal to be able to output something to monitors.

Comment: If your motherboard can't put out to more than 2 displays, the only alternative besides another GPU is using a USB GPU. They aren't that expensive anymore.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen such. Is USB 3.0 throughput enough for 1080p 60 Hz?

Comment: I'm using a wireless GPU that's on USB 2.0 and it supports up to 1080p. I'm not 100% sure about the framerate, but I think it's 60 Hz.

Comment: It is not confirmed it cannot output to more than 2 displays because it has only 2 ports. Maybe there is a feature like daisy-chaining but for DVI or HDMI?

Comment: By the way, could you please recommend a card of such kind just for desktop purposes? I mean without any gaming or heavy computation features.

Comment: Could you tell me which CPU you are using? I will write a detailed answer then. (The CPU is what actually handles the graphics on your motherboard)

Comment: Daisy-chaining is a feature of DisplayPort and not available for HDMI or DVI.

Comment: That's why I said `like`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a USB video adapter for a third monitor. I just put one on a laptop to take it up to three monitors. I used a StarTech USB2DVIPRO2. You can get video card but they are very, very expensive.

Comment: I've ordered a USB Type-C to HDMI adapter. Gonna try, thanks for your help.

Comment: I have received an Algoltek USB-C Billboard. It is a USB Type-C to HDMI adapter. It does not work out of the box. I cannot find any manuals either. Could you please help me to make it working?

Comment: Also, for some reason it works on my laptop as the first external display (and the 2nd overall). Does not work as the 3rd display on my PC where the HDMI and the DVI are already occupied.

Comment: You are 100% at the mercy of the device. I had to download the latest drivers from Startech and even after the drivers were installed it was not obvious how to set it up as a third monitor. I had to go in to Windows display management at that point and assign primary, secondary and tritary monitors. Do they have support for that device that you can contact and does it state plainly that it will support three monitors?